# Multi user task management software

Tags: open-source, project-management, collaboration

I'm looking for a software which can replace my Excel solution I'm using now. I create tasks in an Excel file, people concerned can take it from a share folder, see if any work needs to be done, if so update the file and send it back.

This solution is quite awful to be honest.

What I need:

- Build data from a CSV file (not necessarily like Excel, could be a ticketing software for example)
- Mass task edition (multiple edition in one time)
- Manage permissions (people concerned can only change a row or a cell)
- Bug tracker (like on GitHub)
- Open source is a must

I know this is a very specific question but if anyone has a solution (or several of them which could work together) it will help my searches a lot.

Answer (score 1):

There are several task management applications that may fit your needs. This is what I use:

[bumpy-booby](http://bumpy-booby.derivoile.fr/) - Simple, responsive and highly customizable PHP bug tracking system ([Demo](http://bumpy-booby.derivoile.fr/))

- Can import export/export to JSON (easily convertible to/from CSV)
- Supports user groups and read/write permissions for each.
- No database server required, easy setup (just upload the files to your web server)
- Free Open Source Software (MIT license)

Although it is mainly designed for bug tracking, you can easily use it to keep track of tasks/todo lists, share files...

[TinyIssue](https://github.com/mikelbring/tinyissue/tree/develop) is an alternative which is less bug-tracking oriented, but misses some important features.

Comment: First, thanks for your answer but I'll need more information about bumpy-booby. Maybe I didn't see it but dumpy-booby doesn't display data from a JSON file, it creates task from it right ? I really need to be able to see all raws from my CSV (like on Excel or any ticketing software).